# Check how close UILabels are to each other

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to make a game which has a jumbled up algebra equation. I have assigned an outlet to each component of the equation. For example, if the equation was:

x2 + y = 2(a+b)

Then x2 (which is x squared), +, y, = and 2(a+b) would all be its own outlet. But the equation is going to be jumbled up and I want the user to move the label outlets to the correct order. I have enabled touchesMoved, but my problem lies in checking if the equation is in the correct order. I would wrap the code into an `IBAction` button action, but how do I analyze the text? Would I check for the offset between each label? Is there an easy way/API to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You only would want to check offsets when deciding if a label is in a valid location, or "snapping" them to a valid position.  In order to determine the correct order, you should abstract the whole concept and create components that encapsulate the logic of a piece of an equation.  And then also for a whole equation in general.  Maybe then you can implement some method to check if you have a valid ordering.  Think about the problem/solution in terms of MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your labels are called `xLabel`,`plusLabel`, `yLabel`, `equalsLabel`, and `abLabel`, you could do something like this:

```
NSUInteger xLeftBorder = CGRectGetMinX(xLabel.frame);
NSUInteger plusLeftBorder = CGRectGetMinX(plusLabel.frame);
NSUInteger yLeftBorder = CGRectGetMinX(yLabel.frame);
NSUInteger equalsLeftBorder = CGRectGetMinX(equalsLabel.frame);
NSUInteger abLeftBorder = CGRectGetMinX(abLabel.frame);

if(xLeftBorder < plusLeftBorder && plusLeftBorder < yLeftBorder && yLeftBorder < equalsLeftBorder && equalsLeftBorder < abLeftBorder){

    //Correct!
}

else{
    //Incorrect
}
```

This is kind of clumsy, but it works. An even better way to do it would be to put this in a function with each parameter being a label to check. For example:

```
bool isCorrect = [self checkIf:xLabel isLessThan: plusLabel isLessThan: yLabel isLessThan:equalsLabel isLessThan:abLabel];
```

This is assuming the function you write returns a bool.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks! I am going to check out this code and get back to you in an hour or so!

Comment: Sure. Take your time. However, I'm not sure if I'll be awake in an hour. I'll try to respond to you as soon as possible though.