# iPhone jigsaw puzzle game completion detection

Tags: ios, uiimageview, coordinates

Hi am developing jigsaw puzzle for iPhone.

Here i have almost completed the app except finding whether the jigsaw is complete.

Here each piece is a `UIImageView`, and it has unique tags.

I have tried using x y coordinates, but its no use because user can start fix the puzzle from anywhere in the screen.

So, any idea how to detect whether the images are arranged correctly?

**Edit: Thanks a lot all finally i have done it using co ordinates. by tracing location and tags.**

Comment: How to find whether user has arranged the images correctly in jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: Not knowing how you attach the pieces together, it's kinda hard to help. Try posting some code of what you tried.

Comment: @nik: I'm following your post regarding jigsaw. I've used 9 separate mask images to create irregular shapes for 3x3 jigsaw. But what I see is when you connect those pieces it doesn't form the original image. some part is missing everywhere. Can you please guide me in right direction.

Comment: Yes it should for that you should right the logic to attach the image pieces once it positioned correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have some sort of 'snap to grid' mechanism to put each piece precisely into the correct position once it's close (as would effectively occur with a real jigsaw).  Let's say that this is defined as a specific x,y co-ordinate for the origin of the UIImageView for each piece.

Then, when each piece is in it's correct position (snapped to it's position), set a boolean 'inPlace' for that piece to YES.

When the value for 'inPlace' for all pieces is YES, the jigsaw is complete.

Comment: Thanks I have used the co ordinate concept but not in a way what you have specified here

Comment: @nik Could you please share the logic on how you achieved it?

Answer (score 0):

What about labeling the pieces with id's

Each piece has something like

```
JigsawPiece.Id = 1
```

and label them like this (for a 3x3 puzzle);

```
-------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
-------------
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------
| 6 | 7 |   | 
-------------
```

Add these pieces in a 2D array

```
class JigsawPuzzle:
    array[3][3] JigsawPiece;
```

And finally check if the solution is reached by looking if the numbers are increasing by one.

```
check_id == 1
for int i = 0; i<numrows ; i++
  for int j = 0; j<numcols; j++{  
    if i==numrows - 1 and j==numcols-1: break #last one, which should be empty, skip it             
    solved = jigsawpieces[col][row].id == check_id
    check_id += 1
    if !solved: break;
  }

if solved: You solved it!
```

All is pseudo code because I don't know ObjC

Something along these lines should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Check out my question here: [Check how close UILabels are to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957698/check-how-close-uilabels-are-to-each-other)

It is the same, except I am asking about labels, but you can try to use that with images. I am pretty sure there is a different translation scheme however

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using x y coordinates, but its no use because the user can start fixing it from anywhere in the screen.

You have to select one "base" jigsaw, and get relative coordinates against it for others. Completion check - every piece keeps stored relative position equal to current. Seems, thats all.

Another case if you want to fix puzzle starting random piece and gather by parts (like torn apart image or letter - pieces have different shapes). In this case, for each jigsaw you have to store closest neighbors ids and theirs relative position. If two neighbor pieces are in place - join them.  Condition to win - all neighbors for all pieces are in relative place.